# Maximize console windows in Windows 7

Tags: c, windows

i would like to know how can I maximize windows in Windows 7 OS.

I am using C language.

Answer (score 2):

Do you truly need to maximize the window?  You can achieve something quite similar by using the [SetConsoleWindowInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686125%28VS.85%29.aspx)  function.

Comment: First you must call [`SetConsoleScreenBufferSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686044.aspx), then [`SetConsoleWindowInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686125.aspx).

Comment: Also, [GetLargestConsoleWindowSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683193.aspx) might be useful in this case.

Comment: GetLargestConsoleWindowSize sometimes doesn't give you the accurate information to maximize the console window; I had the similar needs recently so I wrote a simple console app to do this: https://github.com/wangzq/ConsoleMax; it is written using VS 2012 RC as I only had it when I was writing this, but it should be fairly easy to compile it in other VS versions as the only important file is ConsoleMax.cpp. I also added a feature to move the console window to another monitor and maximize itself based on the monitor's work area.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Larry, you could use `SetConsoleWindowInfo`  function to achieve that, Try with this code:

```
int main()
{
   HWND hWnd;
   SetConsoleTitle("test");
   hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, "test");
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD NewSBSize = GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(hOut);
    SMALL_RECT DisplayArea = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hOut, NewSBSize);

    DisplayArea.Right = NewSBSize.X - 1;
    DisplayArea.Bottom = NewSBSize.Y - 1;

    SetConsoleWindowInfo(hOut, TRUE, &DisplayArea);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);
    return 0;
}
```

Please follow this [Thread](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/55672-maximizing-console-window-full-screen.html)